# Testing gestures on openGL ES using the iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, uigesturerecognizer

I have an `openGL ES` app i'm working on, and i added some gestures:

Pan - 1 & 2 fingers, for moving the object

Pinch - Zoom in and out on the object

Rotation - Just to rotate the object

I can't test these gestures on an `iPhone` since mine is currently out of use, and i wanted to know is there any way to test these gestures using `Xcode's` `iPhone` simulator and the `Mac's` touch pad?

Currently i could only test the pan gesture since i can click on the `Mac` touch pad and drag my finger around, so pan does work, but only for 1 finger.

How can i test all the other gestures? is there a way to define that on the `iPhone` simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Hold down the Option key.

[Developer Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Peter says, hold down the option key (alt key on a Windows keyboard) while hovering the mouse over the simulator's screen. That causes 2 points to show on the screen. It's not perfect, but it's better than nothing.

Apple has had multi-touch trackpads and mice for Mac for what, 3 years now, but they still have not added multi-touch support to the simulator. If this was an end-user feature it would have been added years ago. Us developers are not a priority for Apple it seems. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can hold down alt key while pressing left mouse button.